# SQL Email Attachment Troubleshoot

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sp-send-dbmail

I have a script that pulls a file into an email as an attachment and sends it out. It recently has stopped working. 
The file I am pulling is named "DTH201509240918.xlsx" with the last 4 numbers being random so I use '^.*$'. The files are in the source folder, but I always get "no files found". 
Any help would be appreciated on why the file is not being pulled.

```
ALTER Procedure   [dbo].[DSEmail] as begin

declare  @to varchar(1000)          
        ,@sub varchar(1000)         
        ,@subdate varchar(10)       = CONVERT(Varchar(10),GETDATE(),101)
        ,@bod varchar(1000)         
        ,@filePath varchar(1000)    = '\\source\'
        ,@fileDate varchar (8)      = CONVERT(Varchar(8),GETDATE(),112)
        ,@attachments varchar(1000)
        ,@pathAndFile varchar (1000)


Set @attachments = 'DTH' + @fileDate + '^.*$'
Set @pathAndFile = @filePath + @attachments
Set @sub         = 'dS Report ' + @subdate
Set @bod         = '\\source\' + @attachments


Set @to = 'email@email.com'

IF dbo.fn_FileExists(@pathAndFile) = 1
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
             @recipients = @to
            ,@subject = @sub
            ,@body = @bod
            ,@file_attachments = @pathAndFile

ELSE

exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
             @recipients = @to
            ,@subject = 'DS Error'
            ,@body = 'No file was found. Please check \\source\ for today''s file.'

End
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use regex with `master.dbo.fn_FileExists`. The following should be able to get you the exact file names you can attach to your email:

```
declare @dir table
    (
     ID int identity(1, 1)
            primary key
            not null,
     dirEntry nvarchar(max)
    );

insert  into @dir
        (dirEntry)
        exec xp_cmdshell 'dir ' + @filePath + N'*.*';

select  d.dirEntry
from    @dir as d
where   d.dirEntry like N'DTH' + @fileDate + '%.xlsx'
```

Afterwards you can adjust your above code to include the **exact** file name(s) you wish to attach to your email.

Comment: Hello Ralph, 
Thanks for your suggestions.
I am a little confused as to what is being added. So this code should replace the regex I have in place labeled as @attachments in my original code?
I am not sure what to remove and add or what "N' " is for.

If you would be able to explain further, I would be most grateful.
Thank you.